# Filter colours with checkbox input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, input

I'm studing web development and I'm doing a project about a travel agency. In the home I have a big world map where each country is an image and has a class. What I want to do is that when you check an input( for exemple 'Low Cost') the countries where there are flights which their cost is not more expensive than 180 euros change their color to green. By default they have orange color. I have created the images and the inputs, and I have made the JavaScript code, but something is not working because the color doesn't change and there's no errors in the console. So if you could help me a little bit I would be really happy.

I share the html, the css and the JavaScript code.

HTML

```js
var vuelosfrance= {"VuelosFrancia":
                    [

                        {"city":"Paris",
                        "dates":
                            [
                                {"fecha": "15/10/2014","precio": 185 },
                                {"fecha": "16/10/2014","precio": 200 },
                                {"fecha": "19/10/2014","precio": 225 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {"city":"Marsella",
                        "dates":
                            [
                                {"fecha": "15/10/2014","precio": 195 },
                                {"fecha": "18/10/2014","precio": 230 },
                                {"fecha": "20/10/2014","precio": 220 }
                            ]
                        },  
                        
                    ]
                }

// var VuelosSpain = JSON.parse(vuelosspain)


var lowcost = document.getElementById('checkbox_lowcost');

var espana = document.getElementsByClassName('spain');
var espanagreen = document.getElementsByClassName('spaingreen');

function filtrar() {
console.log('a')
        for(i in vuelosspain["VuelosSpain"]) { 
            console.log('b');
            
            for(x in vuelosspain["VuelosSpain"][i]["dates"]) {
                var precio = vuelosspain["VuelosSpain"][i]["dates"][x]["precio"];
                console.log('c')
                if (precio.value < 180) {
                    console.log('d');
                    espana[0].className('spain display');
                    espanagreen[0].className('spaingreen')

                } 
            }
    }
}

if (lowcost.checked == true) {
console.log('e')   filtrar(); };
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 1300px;
background-image: url(../images/nubes.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%
}

.bd {
width: 75%;
margin-left: 75px;
position: relative; }

#checkbox_id {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: top; }

#mapamundo {
display: block; }
.spain {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 24.4%;
left: 41.9%; }

.spaingreen {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 24.4%;
left: 41.9%; }



.portugal {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 26.75%;
left: 41.4%; }

.francia {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 20.1%;
left: 43.6%; }
```

```html
<header><img src="../images/logo2dms300.png"></header>
       
   <ul id="menu">
              <li>
               <p>Cost</p>
                   <ul>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_lowcost" value="value"><p class="textfilters">Low Cost</p></li>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_mediumcost" value="value"><p class="textfilters">Medium Cost</p></li>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_highcost" value="value"><p class="textfilters">High Cost</p></li>
                   </ul>
   
           </li>
           <li>
               <p>Theme</p>
                   <ul>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value"><p class="textfilters">Adventure</p></li>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value"><p class="textfilters">Sun & Beach</p></li>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value"><p class="textfilters">Snow</p></li>
                       <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value"><p class="textfilters">Relax</p></li>
                   </ul>
   
           </li>
   </ul>
   

<section class="bd ilblock">
   <img src="../images/mapas/mapamundidefinitivo.svg.png" id="mapamundo">
   <img src="../images/mapas/spain36default.png" class="spain ">
   <img src="../images/mapas/spain36green.png" class="spaingreen display">
   <img src="../images/mapas/portugal18default.png" class="portugal display">
   <img src="../images/mapas/portugal18green.png" class="portugal">
   <img src="../images/mapas/francia31default.png" class="francia display">
   <img src="../images/mapas/francia31green.png" class="francia">
</section>
```

Comment: Its really hard to debug just the code. please do a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). so we can give a better reply

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's really hard code to look at, but if you want to change the countries based on a checkbox, try this:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
var cheapCountries = document.getElementsByClassName("cheap");

checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        for (var i=0; i < cheapCountries.length; i++) {
            cheapCountries[i].style.background = "green";            
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i=0; i < cheapCountries.length; i++) {
            cheapCountries[i].style.background = "orange";            
        }   
    }
});
```

Just a simple checkbox handler that finds all the countries (divs) you have on your map with the class name = cheap, then changes their background colour. Or you could use addClass and removeClass.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks very good but I have to do it with JavaScript unfortunately. By the way I dont get where (".cheap") comes from. Is it a Class??

Comment: Oh, okay, I updated to vanilla js.. Yeah, it's a class that you would put on each of the countries you wanted to highlight when you clicked the cheap (or low cost) checkbox..

Comment: Well I have another problem now :( The problem is that cheap is a class that countries doesn't have in my html, because I need that when my checkbox is checked the machine look in the database the price of the flights and according to that execute the change of color. That's why I created an object called VuelosSpain and a variable called vuelosspain that contains those dates inside the property 'precio'.