# Get a variable from a property of an object

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to create a variable from an object. I know this is very easy but I'm very new in JavaScript, so I hope someone help me.

I have this object and a I need to get a variable that contains the value of property `precio`.

```
var vuelosspain= {"VuelosSpain":
[
    {
     "city":"Madrid",
     "dates":
      [
         {"fecha": "15/10/2014","precio": 50 },
         {"fecha": "16/10/2014","precio": 40 },
         {"fecha": "19/10/2014","precio": 45 }
      ]
    },
    {
     "city":"Barcelona",
     "dates":
      [
          {"fecha": "15/10/2014","precio": 55 },
          {"fecha": "18/10/2014","precio": 35 },
          {"fecha": "20/10/2014","precio": 25 }
      ]
   }  
]}
```

This is my try

```
var precio = vuelosspain["VuelosSpain"][i]["dates"][x]["precio"]
```

Comment: `console.log(vuelosspain["VuelosSpain"][1]["dates"][1]["precio"]);` gives `35` - so what actually is your problem? see http://jsfiddle.net/htn1curg/

Comment: What are `i` and `x`? How did you come up with those variables? Is your code in a loop? What parts don't you understand?

Comment: ...it seems from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555236/filter-colours-with-checkbox-input-in-javascript) that you already have the appropriate loops. So what's the issue exactly?

Comment: ...and here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ou369nh/) using your previous code. It works just fine.

Comment: i and x are variables in a loop, because I need that JavaScript look for in all the 'precio' property and get me the value. So thta's why I created this function, but it doesnt work out in the browser, and I think is because it doesn't recognise the variable precio